# How can I open a 3D .npy file in R or MATLAB?

Tags: python, arrays, r, matlab, numpy

I have .npy files of the shape[512, 512, x] with x going up to maximally 400. In these arrays (is that the right term? I'm not sure about the right terminology), there are floating point numbers between zero and one. They are grey levels of a noise image. The image is 512x512 pixels and per npy file I have a different number of images that I saved.

I now would like to do some computations with the noise images but have been unable to import the arrays in R or MATLAB:

In R I tried the [RcppCNPy](https://www.getdatajoy.com/learn/Read_and_Write_Numpy_Binary_files_from_R) - package and got the error "unsupported dimension in npyLoad".

In MATLAB, I tried the [readNPY](https://github.com/kwikteam/npy-matlab) - function and got the error "This file does not appear to be NUMPY format based on the header." But my file has no header. Could it be that the function only works for 2D arrays?

How could I access the 3D-array that I saved before?

Any help in MATLAB or R would be very much appreciated!

Comment: In R or in MATLAB? They are very different

Comment: Contact the `readNpy` developers directly.  The package is too new.

Comment: Either  R or MATLAB, although I think I would prefer a MATLAB solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`npy` is a unique `numpy` file format.  And yes, it does have a header block that contains information like version, dimensions, strides, and dtype.

A quick glance at the `readNpy` shows it is relatively new and experimental.  Check with them about capabilities.

`np.savetxt` writes text `CSV` files.  This is widely used (look at the number of SO question about `np.genfromtxt` and `np.loadtxt`), but by the very nature of 'paper' is 2d - lines of columns.  I don't know of any standard to write higher dimensional arrays - reshaping to 2d and back is probably the simplest.

`scipy.io.savemat` can write MATLAB compatible `.mat` files.  This (and `loadmat`) is capable of reading/writing higher D arrays, and MATLAB structures and cells.  This is the best tested file interchange between `numpy` and MATLAB.

A newer MATLAB save format uses HDF5 files.  The Python `h5py` package can read and write those as well.  There have been a scattering of SO questions about reading this type of file as produced by MATLAB.  [Python-created HDF5 dataset transposed in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21624653/python-created-hdf5-dataset-transposed-in-matlab)

Keep in mind that MATLAB dimension ordering is equivalent to the `numpy` 'F' order.

Compare:

```
xf=np.arange(12).reshape(3,4,order='F')   # saved with savemat

>> xf(:).'      # in octave
ans =
   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11
```

without the order=F, octave gives

```
 0   4   8   1   5   9   2   6  10   3   7  11
```

and

```
>> xf
xf =
   0   3   6   9
   1   4   7  10
   2   5   8  11

>> x
x =
   0   1   2   3
   4   5   6   7
   8   9  10  11
```

`np.asfortranarray(x)` doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Thanks for the ordering remark! If I understand it correctly, to get the same array of values in MATLAB that was created in NumPy, I should use  numpy.asfortranarray when creating the array, right?

Comment: Try it.  `savemat` may do it anyways.  Look at the order of values in the raveled versions, before and after.  `loadmat` gives you `order F` files.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to python and numpy, a workaround is to load the .npy files with [`np.load()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html), then save them in txt format with [`np.savetxt()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html).

EDIT: It seems that savetxt() does not work with 3D arrays, so in python2 you can use file() to sequentially write 2D entries of your array:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(60).reshape(3, 4, 5)
with file("test.txt", 'w') as f:
    for slice in a:
        np.savetxt(f, a)
```

You could also reshape a to a 2D array, use savetxt, then load it in csv/Matlab and reshape it.

Comment: Thank you for your idea. I just tried it and unfortunately, it dosen't work: As long as the Array is 2D, it's fine, but as soon as the third dimension is bigger than 1, it crashes with the error: "Mismatch between array dtype ('float64') and format specifier". My specifier is '%f', and since it works fine for the first noise image and only crashes after the second one is generated, I think the error really has to do with the dimensions of the array...

Comment: If you are using python2, you can use the file() built in function to save the 2D slices of the array (see my edit)

Comment: would I then get a new file for each slice? Since the slices correspond to trial numbers of one person, I would rather keep them together...

Comment: @lilla no, they are written consecutively. Alternatively, reshape a to a 2D array, and when you load it in Matlab or R reshape it (since you know its original shape)

Comment: Savetxt is only for 2d arrays.  Scipy.io.savemat can create matlab compatible mat files