# Why the form of matrix taken from matlab change when reading them by to python

Tags: python, matlab, matrix

I have a big file saved from matlab with version -v7.3, when reading it by python, the shape of matrix change !! is that normal ?

For example, let's have the below matrix in MATLAB,

```
clear all, clcl 
A = randn(10,3) + randn(10,3)*i;
save('example.mat','-v7.3');     %% The saved file is example.mat with version 7.3
```

above, the saved file is example.mat a matrix of size (10,3)

so, let's go to python to read that file :

```
import numpy as np
import h5py as h5 

data_try = h5.File('example.mat', 'r')
A = np.array(data_try) 
A = A.view(np.complex)  #here the matrix equivalent to that one in matlab
```

but what i find that A in python is of size (3,10) !!  and also when having matrix of three dimensions, the shape is changing !!

Is that normal that python reads the transpose of matrix coming from matlab ??!! or something wrong is happening !
However when using the other way as below:

```
import scipy.io as spio
Data = spio.loadmat('example.mat', squeeze_me=True)
A = Data[‘A’]
```

in that case, everything is really nice, but unfortunately we can not use that way for big matrices !!!

please, any solution for that issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You might face a problem with different memory alignment in Matlab (column-major) and Numpy (row-major)... check e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20341614/numpy-array-row-major-and-column-major) for related discussion and a solution (reshaping in Fortran-style, which is also column-major).

SciPy's `.mat` interface automatically takes care of this reinterpretation, which is why you don't encounter the problem when using it.

Comment: That case is totally different.

Comment: Indeed, your problem is simply solved by a `A = A.transpose()`. Maybe [this duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21624653/python-created-hdf5-dataset-transposed-in-matlab) sheds more light on your question?