# De-referening an hdf5 format?

Tags: python, matlab, python-2.7, h5py

I am working with two different languages i.e. Matlab and python. I created 5 variables in Matlab. Each variable has a size- (150x1) cells as shown below:

[image]

Each cell has a size of (128 x (:)) as shown below:

[image]

I saved this workspace into a .mat file using -v7.3 which is a hdf5 format.

In python, I loaded the .mat file using h5py. I was able to load the variables but I am unable to extract the values from each variable.

I get this statement "array([[], dtype=object)" but the values are not loaded into the python workspace. I would like to load all the 150 cells o into a variable say A. How do I de-reference the hdf5 reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should save the data in a regular hdf5 file. The .mat file is based on hdf5, but it is not a plain hdf5 file.

In MATLAB you can do it natively using 
http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/exporting-to-hierarchical-data-format-hdf5-files.html

Comment: Thank you.  I will surely consider that.. But is there any possibility of solving this using mat file?

Comment: Put sample code to see how you are trying it please.

Comment: The code is given below:
`import h5py ` 
`f = h5py.File('D:/Thesis/python svm/AFN.mat','r')`
I tried the soultions in  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27670149/read-matlab-v7-3-file-into-python-list-of-numpy-arrays-via-h5py) But there the size of the cell was constant.

Answer (score 0):

To de-reference, use:

```
f[ref]
```

where `f` is the `h5py.File` object and `ref` is the `<HDF5 object reference>` object.

See the [h5py documentation on references](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/refs.html)