# Transpose list subset dimension?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, transpose

I have a list with 2 cells, each of them is 3 dimension array, one is 3 by 4 by 5, the other is 6 by 7 by 8. Need to transpose the subset in the list to be like: 5 by 4 by 3, and 8 by 7 by 6, I used `array.transpose([2,1,0])`, got the error `axes don't match`.

Comment: Use `numpy.swapaxes`.

Comment: @MadPhysicist will try, but now I got another issue, seems one axes missing when I read the file from h5py

Comment: Print the shape of your arrays, the commands you are running, the actual, full errors you are getting. Your comments don't match what you are saying in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `numpy.ndarray.transpose()` function instead. Seems like that's closer to what you're looking for.

Documentation:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.transpose.html

Comment: Use ndarray, I got the error: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars.

Comment: @xman Convert the list to an array with `np.asarray(input_list)` and then try `swapaxes` or `transpose`.

Comment: @Divakar I got another issue now, the h5py file I read from "*.mat" with 2 cells (each of them 3 dimension, 3*4*5 and 6*7*8) now only the 2nd and 3rd axes left after np.array(), and dimension seems to be like (2*4*5) and (2*7*8).

Comment: @xman Ah my bad! I got your question wrongly it seems. So, I think you can process each cell separately. So, if the input list is named `input_list`, you can use `swapaxes` or `transpose` on `input_list[0]` and so on.

Comment: The way I read .mat is here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27670149/read-matlab-v7-3-file-into-python-list-of-numpy-arrays-via-h5py)

Comment: @Divakar I tried, not work for me.... my problem now is one of the axes missing...

Comment: @Divakar Yes, that's what I was doing. After cell[0].transpose([2,1,0]), it shows that cell[0].shape is still (3, 4, 5), but I want it to be (5, 4, 3)...

Comment: @Divakar Thank you, I'm using pdb debugging, just want to get the array with correct dimension.

Comment: @Divakar Thank you so much!!! I forgot to save it back! Now it works! :)