# Python hdf5storage is transposing my data?

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py, hdf5storage

Python Code:

```
import h5py
import hdf5storage
from functools import reduce
import numpy as np
from operator import mul

sz = 128,256,512
a = np.random.normal(size=reduce(mul,sz)).reshape(sz)
save_dict = {'data':a}

spath = r"test.mat"
hdf5storage.savemat(spath, mdict=save_dict, append_mat=False, 
                    store_python_metadata=True, format='7.3')

with h5py.File(spath, 'r') as file:
    b = np.array(file['data'])

# Reads in the correct shape, but is F-contiguous. Scipy doesn't work with v7.3 files.
c = hdf5storage.loadmat(spath)['data']
```

When a is created, it has a shape (128,256,512). However, when I save a to the .mat file using hdf5storage, and then load it into b using h5py, b is transposed as has a shape of (512,256,128). Both arrays are C-contiguous when checking their flags.

Is there any way to prevent this transpose from happening? I was under the impression that hdf5 format saves row-major.

Comment: The MATLAB convention is F-contiguous.  You can see that in the arrays loaded via `scipy.io.loadmat`.  The `HDF5` convention is C-contiguous.  I've just looked a bit at the HDF5 files produced by MATLAB/Octave (using `h5py`).  I don't know what kinds of games `hdf5storage` is playing with these conventions.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46044613/how-to-import-mat-v7-3-file-using-h5py

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know of anything else that supports v7.3 .mat files. When trying to use scipy, an error pops up saying to using h5py for that types of files. And I have colleagues that use MATLAB only, so I'm trying to create data files (.mat) that we can pass back and forth easily.

Comment: As long as you are interacting with MATLAB you'll have to deal with order differences and transposes.  In numpy the first axis is the outermost.  In MATLAB it's the last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked again at the `abc.h5` file described in:

[how to import .mat-v7.3 file using h5py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46044613/how-to-import-mat-v7-3-file-using-h5py)

It was created in Octave with:

```
>> A = [1,2,3;4,5,6];
>> B = [1,2,3,4];
>> save -hdf5 abc.h5 A B
```

Using `h5py`:

```
In [102]: f = h5py.File('abc.h5','r')
In [103]: A = f['A']['value'][:]
In [104]: A
Out[104]: 
array([[1., 4.],
       [2., 5.],
       [3., 6.]])
In [105]: A.shape
Out[105]: (3, 2)
In [106]: A.flags
Out[106]: 
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  ...
In [107]: A.ravel()
Out[107]: array([1., 4., 2., 5., 3., 6.])
```

So it's a transposed C order array.  Apparently that's how MATLAB developers have chosen to store their matrices in HDF5.

I could tranpose it in numpy:

```
In [108]: At = A.T
In [109]: At
Out[109]: 
array([[1., 2., 3.],
       [4., 5., 6.]])
In [110]: At.flags
Out[110]: 
  C_CONTIGUOUS : False
  F_CONTIGUOUS : True
  ....
```

As is normal, a C-order array becomes F-order when transposed.

The Octave matrices saved with the older .mat format

```
In [115]: data = io.loadmat('../abc.mat')
In [116]: data['A']
Out[116]: 
array([[1., 2., 3.],
       [4., 5., 6.]])
In [117]: _.flags
Out[117]: 
  C_CONTIGUOUS : False
  F_CONTIGUOUS : True
```

So the `h5py` array, transposed, matches the convention that `io.loadmat` has been using for quite some time.

I don't have `hdf5storage` installed on this OS.  But by your tests, it is following the `io.loadmat` convention - correct shape but F order.