# how to access fields of .mat file opened with h5py

Tags: arrays, matlab, h5py

I have a structure `S` that I have stored in a .mat file I built with MATLAB -v7.3 (because the struct was too large, >2GB requires -v7.3). Unfortunately, now I cannot open my files with `spio.loadmat('myfile.mat')` so I am opening it with `h5py`:

```
f = h5py.File('myfile.mat')
```

My struct, `S`, has 3 fields and a size of 700.

Ex.

```
S(1).field1 = some array
S(1).field2 = some array
S(1).field3 = some array
....
S(700).field1 = some array
S(700).field2 = some array
S(700).field3 = some array
```

My question is, how do I access these fields and some array values in the h5py format? Using `f`?

Comment: Start by exploring the nested `group` and `dataset` keys.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/27699851/901925.  Look on the sidebar for other links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
idx = f['S/field1'][0][0]  #serves as an index where f contains the field object
field1_object = f[idx] #access the field object
field1_content = field1_object.value #reveal the array

...

idx = f['S/field2'][699][0]
field2_object = f[idx]
field2_content = field2_object.value
```